# If $ a,b,c$ are in descending order of magnitude how to prove $(\frac{a+c}{a-c})^a <(\frac{b+c}{b-c})^b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $ a,b,c$ are in descending order of magnitude how to prove $$\left(\frac{a+c}{a-c}\right)^a <\left( \frac{b+c}{b-c}\right)^b$$

I was trying to solve taking log on both sides.
LHS becomes $a\log(\frac{a+c}{a-c}) = a\log(1+\frac{2c}{a-c})$
Similarly RHS becomes $b\log(\frac{b+c}{b-c}) = b\log(1+\frac{2c}{b-c})$

Expanded both sides as $\log(1+x)$. Finally could not prove as both positive and negative terms are there. Please let me know how to compare the terms after expansion or any other methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $a>b>c$. Do you want $c>0$ too? Let's assume so. The inequality is equivalent to
$$f(1/a)<f(1/b)$$
where
$$f(x)=\frac1x\ln\left(\frac{1+cx}{1-cx}\right).$$
The Maclaurin series of this has positive coefficients, so it's
increasing for $0<x<1/c$.

Comment: Thanks. However, looking for a solution without the use of calculus.